# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10) SwiftUI @main app

Tags: swift, memory, swiftui

I keep getting the Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10) error at random times in my app's startup. I am using SwiftUI and Xcode will not point out where which deallocated object is trying to access.

As you can see from the screenshot, the debugger is not helpful as it does not give any hints on where the problem might be. I have tried setting Exception Breakpoints without any success.

The weirdest part is that this error pops up at my app's startup, but randomly, not constantly.

Does anybody have any experience with debugging these kinds of issues?

[image]

Comment: `2023-02-21 22:23:35.139236+0100 ImNotScared[2951:838579] Metal API Validation Enabled`

`2023-02-21 22:23:35.324270+0100 ImNotScared[2951:838579] [PipelineLibrary] Mapping the pipeline data cache failed, errno 22`

`2023-02-21 22:23:35.367297+0100 ImNotScared[2951:838579] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""`


These are the debug logs that come right before the app crashes

Comment: That is usually a timing issue. Something you are doing is asynchronous and causing issues.

Comment: @loremipsum I have managed to reproduce the bug and it always happens after logging out with firebase and then signing back in

Comment: That is usually async work, I would switch to the new `async await` versions of those methods and get rid of any `DispatchQueue` calls that you may have in there

Comment: That's why I just refactored but unfortunately no updates. 

I have found that we can attribute the object at which the memory access was attempted by running

`expr -l c -O -- 0x10`

It returns me `16`, an integer, and I really don't know how to interpret that.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS out of the blue, cleaning the build folder fixes it. This seems to be an Xcode issue.

Comment: Thank you so much @viedev, it appears the error has gone after cleaning the build folder. Why does that happen though? Is this an Xcode issue or should I worry about these crashes in production too?

Comment: Also, after a few trials, the error came back.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is some sort of build data caching issue in Xcode. Haven't found a pattern yet though, I just it seems to occur more frequently when working on certain files in my project. A clean always fixes this for me, but it's really annoying. Sometimes I just change a tiny detail (like adding a single modifier) and I get the error. After cleaning it works again, but this can slow you down quite a bit.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue. The strange thing is, I sometimes get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error related to a `View`. It appears that the error I'm facing isn't stemming from the logic of the code, such as nil unwrapping or accessing an index out of bounds, which are typical causes of these errors. Instead, it's being triggered on seemingly random lines, pointing to some `View` type in the view hierarchy. It doesn't seem to make sense, and I haven't been able to find a logical explanation for it. However, your advice to **clean the build folder works**! Xcode Version 14.2.

Comment: You are a legend